# Is ToQuery only suitable for testing?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In Entity Frameowork Core you can define a so called query on your context using modelBuilder.Query.ToQuery(). In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/july/data-points-ef-core-2-1-query-types#the-new-defining-query-feature) it says that it is an alternative to adding SQL views to the context that allows for in-memory testing. Say I would feel more comfortable with mapping LINQ expressions to a view model rather than mapping to a SQL view, is ToQuery suitable for that under a production workload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in such matters, it always is, until its not.
What i mean by that is that i have used the same method, and while not used under "enormus" loads of traffic, it can easily handle a "small/medium" traffic solution.
So until it becomes a chokepoint, and because it is stable enough as a feature to be used with production, i dont see any reason not to go for it.

That been said, if at any point the load gets "too big" you can always opt in later on for a proper view, that will always make sure that db optimizations are been used effectively!

Also note that the way you will be using the object is crucial. Added in "simple" selects is always fine, but making complex calls over it, could make things "bloat" or ,just assuming here, cause client-evaluation conflicts on complex queries

Comment: "until it becomes a chokepoint", can ToQuery be more of a chokepoint than a regular LINQ query on a DbSet?

Comment: No, they amount to the same thing at the end, but because it will be exposed just like any other entity, at some point people might forget that its not at its "optimal state" and abuse it, or include it without it been required. The advantage of making the view is that the database frame will probably be able to make it work "faster", and let entity just deserialize the response, rather than constructing the select every time and running it ( but there are cachings involved, its not compiled every time, this is what makes it a good enough solution until its the main trouble maker of the path )